# Python mysqldb error closing connection

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, python-2.4

I'm having a problem when closing a connection as follows:

```
   database = 'sed_database'   
   conn = MySQLdb.Connect(host='remote_host', user='default',
                          passwd='pass', db=database)    
   try:
      try:
         cursor = conn.cursor()
         cursor.execute(sql_str)
         results = cursor.fetchall()
      except MySQLdb.Error, e:
         print "MySQL/Server Error using query: %s" % sql_str
         print "Using database: %s" % database
         raise e
   finally:
      if cursor:
         cursor.close()
      if conn:
         conn.close()
```

This gives:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trass.py", line 579, in ?
    main(sys.argv)
  File "trass.py", line 555, in main
    old_rows, changes_list = auto_analyse_test(f, args.build, args.quiet, args.debug)
  File "trass.py", line 352, in auto_analyse_test
    last_analysed_build = get_sed_baseline_ref(test_file_name, old_delivery_stream)
  File "trass.py", line 151, in get_sed_baseline_ref
    results = execute_sql_query(sql, delivery_stream)
  File "trass.py", line 197, in execute_sql_query
    passwd='pass', db=database)
  File "C:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 75, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 164, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.InternalError: (3, "Error writing file 'D:\\MySQL_Datafiles\\Logfiles\\query.
log' (Errcode: 9)")
```

Python's MySQLDB library info is as follows:

```
>>> print MySQLdb.get_client_info()
4.1.18
>>> print MySQLdb.__version__
1.2.1_p2
>>> print MySQLdb.__revision__
410
```

What is strange is that:

- I've checked on the server and query.log exists and is being written to by other processes.
- This code works through several iterations, then on a particular item it fails.
- The exact query runs fine via SQLyog and yields four results.

The server error.log says "Aborted connection... (Got an error reading comminication packets)"

While the Traceback appears to show the error being associated with the connection creation, it doesn't occur until the connection is closed (or the function ends, which I guess closes it by default). I've tried putting extra output or pauses between open and close. Every time the exception occurs on the close. So what could cause this error on closing the connection?

Comment: That error seems to be in code creating the connection which is not in the code your show. What is the full stack trace, the one showing the call your code made?

Comment: Are you opening connection at each iteration? Maybe this could consume your mysql instances resources.

Comment: @scriptmonster Yes, I'm opening it every time, but also closing it every time. Surely that's OK?

Comment: Does the MySQL process have write permissions to `query.log`?

Comment: @rednaw, I think so. It seems to be working for other incoming queries.

Comment: Could you check the mysql error log? There might be some extra information in there. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-log.html

Comment: Something weird is going on here. I've copied the section of code which is connecting to the DB into a new script for debugging, but with the same MySQLdb calls and query and the problem does not occur.

Comment: Ah yes, the error log says "Aborted connection... (Got an error reading comminication packets)"

Comment: The reason for the error itself might not be so odd since you mentioned other processes are writing to it, this will cause Python to try a o+w operation on a locked file. Try removing the try blocks and give us the row causing the "reading communication" error, because this code and it's error message will not really give us much to go on.

Comment: please specify which mysql library you are using, what exact version thereof and if you connect to local or remote host.

Comment: @Torxed, I've removed the try...except...finally blocks, but the stack trace is identical to that above.

Comment: @qarma, I've edited in the MySQLdb version info.

Comment: @JamesBradbury Well it says the error is in `execute_sql_query` which is a function you've made which you havn't posted? It also states the error is with `passwd='pass', db=database)` which isn't part of the code you've posted?

Comment: @Torxed The code is the body of execute_sql_query(). I've now included the connection object creation.

Comment: @qarma I am connecting to a remote host (which I also have admin access to). This host appears to be working reliably for several other users.

Comment: use http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx to determain which other processes is writing or using the `.log` file, kill them and where have you defined the log to be written to `:\\MySQL_Datafiles` or is that a default behavior of this module?

Comment: @Torxed If the problem was other processes trying to write to the file, then shouldn't I expect intermittent failures on all queries/code instead of consistent failure from one script? In any case, I can't go killing the other MySQL server processes as the server is live and in constant use.

Comment: Was just curious what other processes was accessing it. I'm not entirely sure this is an actual Python related issue. I just get this weird feeling that this is an error produced by the SQL server itself, and it's the server that can't write to the file. Because you havn't specified this log location from what i understand and the only application that knows about it in that case is the server, thus telling us that this is a server produced error message simply stating that it couldn't log your request but it did execute it?

Comment: No, I suspect it's a MySQL/server issue, perhaps I should ask a question elsewhere. It seems the request is not being executed as I don't get results back. When run from SQLyog I get results and no error messages.

Comment: re "xtra output or pauses between open and close", errors and extra output go through disparate channels, stderr and stdio. thus you may see them out of order.

Comment: what is mysql server version? if it is much newer, may i suggest upgrading the client libmysql and MySQLdb? see client version 4.1.x is really really old.

Comment: The server is 5.0. It's some hassle to upgrade everyone on the project to a more recent MySQLdb (and possibly a later Python?) but as you say it may be a solution.

Comment: I only propose that you test it. python version doesn't matter. Only libmysql so/dll and MySQLdb module. For example, user authentication is different in old mysql. then there's a chance that this particular module version has a bug.

Comment: Python version may matter as it appears you can't get an updated MySQLdb for 2.4.

Comment: fine, as long as you test new client libraries in same scenario :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I found so far.

It appears that error is triggered when opening a connection, at `MySQLdb.Connect(...)`, 2nd line in pasted code, not when closing a connection.

Full backtrace:

- ...
- execute_sql_query [op]
- MySQLdb Connect [op]
- MySQLdb super(...) [op]
- _mysql.c ConnectionObject_Initialize [lower level pyhon module, written in C]
- libmysql mysql_real_connect or mysql_options [probably the earlier]
- fails, exception is set

Let's decode the exception

```
InternalError:
    (3,
     "Error writing file 'D:\\MySQL_Datafiles\\Logfiles\\query.log'
                         (Errcode: 9)")
```

- "3" older mysql mysys_err.h `EE_WRITE` 3
- "query.log", is this local or remote log file? appears to be a windows path.
- "Errorcode: 9" assuming windows (above), that is `ERROR_INVALID_BLOCK` "The storage control block address is invalid." Quite cryptic, but it'd go and check if this file exist, if it is writeable, and if it may be subject to logrotate or similar. Check disk space, for a good measure, do a disk check as well.

It appears to be a client-side error. Please check your client-side `my.cnf`, `[client]` section.

[source code for given MySQLdb version](https://github.com/farcepest/moist/tree/b9e1b7aabf5ddede0337c5a5730dd84a3c6272b1/MySQLdb)

Comment: Thanks for the analysis... query.log resides on the Windows server, is some 4GB in size, doesn't have read-only status or anything and was last written to a month ago. In the same directory error.log is written to on a daily basis.

Comment: last written a month ago is suspect. perhaps filesystem limits file to 4GB in size (FAT32).

Comment: also, please check if client is trying to write file with this name and cannot, e.g. because given folders don't exist.

Comment: Well I renamed the query.log and created a new, empty query.log, but I get the same error.

Comment: I think it's critical to determine if this error happens on the client or server. You could check data transmission with wireshark/tcpdump, or which files client tries to access with process monitor/windbg logger.exe/straceNT/xperf/usch-poc.

Comment: +1 for your effort. I don't think this solves it, but I appreciate the helpful suggestions.